# Why does my ESS R session fall back to C locale?

Tags: r, macos, emacs, environment-variables, ess

I'm on OSX Yosemite running Emacs 24.5 and R 3.2

I have this in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

this in my emacs settings:

```
(setq current-language-environment "UTF-8")

(add-hook 'ess-R-post-run-hook
      (lambda () (set-buffer-process-coding-system
                  'utf-8-nfd-unix 'utf-8-nfd-unix)))
```

And I've even set the following system-wide:

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

When I run R from the command line or in RStudio, it uses the correct locale. When I run an R process in emacs though, I get the following warning:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"
```

And any non-ASCII characters are malformed producing errors. How can I set the correct locale?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear when running Emacs from Terminal, which led me to the solution, see below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is not in Emacs, ESS or R it is that in OSX processes launched through launchd do not inherit any environment variables in .profile, .bash_profile or .bashrc. Instead, one must set the environment through launchd.

Doing this solved my problem:

```
/bin/launchctl setenv LANG en_US.UTF-8
/bin/launchctl setenv LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
/bin/launchctl setenv LC_CTYPE en_US.UTF-8
/bin/launchctl setenv LC_COLLATE en_US.UTF-8
/bin/launchctl setenv LC_MESSAGES en_US.UTF-8
/bin/launchctl setenv LC_TIME en_US.UTF-8
/bin/launchctl setenv LC_MONETARY en_US.UTF-8
```

To persist the environment variables across reboots, add an entry in [/Library/LaunchDaemons/](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-mac-os-x-launchd-plist/) (OSX > 10.9).
For earlier versions add it in [/etc/launchd.conf](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-mac-os-x-slash-etc-slash-launchd-dot-conf/) instead.

The above will set the environment variables for *all* processes started via launchd. If this is not desirable one can edit the Info.plist file in an individual .app file and set the variables as key-values in a dict with key `LSEnvironment`

For example, to solve the problem in Emacs I edited the file:

/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app/Contents/Info.plist

Adding the following entry in the top-level dict:

```
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
  <key>LANG</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_ALL</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_CTYPE</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_COLLATE</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_PAPER</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_ADDRESS</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_MONETARY</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_NUMERIC</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_TELEPHONE</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_MESSAGES</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_IDENTIFICATION</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_MEASUREMENT</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_TIME</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
  <key>LC_NAME</key>
  <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
</dict>
```

(Not all variables are strictly required of course)

Comment: Would just setting the variables on emacs do the trick? like so ";; -- environment set
(setenv "LANG"        "UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_CTYPE"    "UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_NUMERIC"  "UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_TIME"     "UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_COLLATE"  "UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_MONETARY" "UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_MESSAGES" "UTF-8")

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that you just have to add

```
(unless (getenv "LANG") (setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8"))
```

to your .emacs.el file.

This sets the environmental variable `LANG` in emacs if it is not set already. This seems to be all that is required by R.

This is a much less intrusive approach and works from within emacs.

Comment: Adding additional `(unless (getenv "LC_ALL") (setenv "LC_ALL" "en_US.UTF-8"))` works for me.